# What are the criteria for putting a question less than 5 years old on the front page after editing it to include info from a newly-cited source?

Tags: support

When I had attempted to edit an answer so as to add some detail, I was told that details should be included in comments, as an edit would cause the question and its answer to display on the front page.  However, a recent edit, adding new and highly-relevant information to the answer of a question less than 5 years old, as well as citing the source of the information, did not result in any new display on the front page.  Might the decision-making process determining an additional display of a question on the front page be described?

Comment: Can you link to the posts you are discussing?

Comment: It was the answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105895/is-the-universe-past-eternal/215986#215986 , but I believe I may have added the parenthetical remark showing as the end of my last edit "within the 5-min. grace period" after posting that last edit.  The parenthetical remark is off-the-beam enough that it's giving me a pain anyway, so I guess I'll edit it away and see what happens (as nullifying it in a comment would be excessively convoluted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing questions and answers always<sup>1</sup> bumps the question to the front page, as long as the question has a score greater than -4.

If you didn't see a question you edited on the front page, it's possible that you have set one of its tags to be ignored. You can check that at https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/.

<sup>1</sup>There are a few exceptions that don't apply here. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/380389) if you want all the details.

Comment: The PSE question's score's high enough, and no answer to it has so far been accepted, but I see that my deletion, rewriting, and undeletion of my answer to it (all of which occurred, in the sequence mentioned, after my posting of my question to Meta) would not have put it on the front page.  Oh well.

Comment: @Edouard As I read the link, the edit to the deleted answer should still have bumped the question.